# i have array in phtml template ,want pass it to web/html template any help?

Tags: magento2

i have array in phtml template ,want pass it to web/html template 
any help? magento 2
send  names arrat to web/html/template

$names=  $blockObj->getRuleName($val);

Comment: did you try using knockoutjs?

Comment: can you explain how use knockoutjs for that purpose @SohelRana

Answer (score 0):

$names= $blockObj->getRuleName($val);
foreach ( $names as $name )
{ echo $name; }

That's all.